IPSec S2S access other machines on the other end subnet
I have an IPsec tunnel from node a (network A) to node b (network B)
I can ping from one machine the other internal ip and it works fine
Now I've a db server on network B that I want to access from node a
when doing telnet 10.1.2.154 14917 from node b, it works fine
but doing it from node a I get: telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: No route to host
config:
config setup
    protostack=netkey

conn mytunnel
    left=147.135.xx.xxx
    right=135.148.xxx.xxx
    authby=secret
    auto=start
    leftsubnet=10.1.0.0/16
    rightsubnet=10.3.0.0/16
    leftsourceip=10.1.0.191
    rightsourceip=10.3.1.122


ip route on node a:
default via 10.3.0.1 dev ens4 proto dhcp src 10.3.1.122 metric 100
default via 135.148.xxx.x dev ens3 proto dhcp src 135.148.xxx.xxx metric 100
10.1.0.0/16 dev ens3 scope link src 10.3.1.122
10.3.0.0/16 via 135.148.xxx.xxx dev ens3
10.3.0.0/16 dev ens4 proto kernel scope link src 10.3.1.122 metric 100
10.3.0.1 dev ens4 proto dhcp scope link src 10.3.1.122 metric 100
10.3.0.3 dev ens4 proto dhcp scope link src 10.3.1.122 metric 100
135.148.xxx.x dev ens3 proto dhcp scope link src 135.148.xxx.xxx metric 100
169.254.169.254 via 10.3.0.3 dev ens4 proto dhcp src 10.3.1.122 metric 100
213.186.33.99 via 10.3.0.1 dev ens4 proto dhcp src 10.3.1.122 metric 100
213.186.33.99 via 135.148.xxx.x dev ens3 proto dhcp src 135.148.xxx.xxx metric 100


ip route on node b:
default via 10.1.0.1 dev ens4 proto dhcp src 10.1.0.191 metric 100
default via 147.135.xx.x dev ens3 proto dhcp src 147.135.xx.xxx metric 100
10.1.0.0/16 dev ens4 proto kernel scope link src 10.1.0.191 metric 100
10.1.0.1 dev ens4 proto dhcp scope link src 10.1.0.191 metric 100
10.1.0.3 dev ens4 proto dhcp scope link src 10.1.0.191 metric 100
10.3.0.0/16 dev ens3 scope link src 10.1.0.191
147.135.xx.x dev ens3 proto dhcp scope link src 147.135.xx.xxx metric 100
169.254.169.254 via 10.1.0.3 dev ens4 proto dhcp src 10.1.0.191 metric 100
213.186.33.99 via 10.1.0.1 dev ens4 proto dhcp src 10.1.0.191 metric 100
213.186.33.99 via 147.135.xx.x dev ens3 proto dhcp src 147.135.xx.xxx metric 100

what am I doing wrong?
